# Cannot make Polly Timeout Policy override the HttpClient default timeout

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

I am using a Polly retry policy and as expected during that retry processes the `HttpClient` hits its 100 second timeout.  I have tried a couple of different ways to incorporate the Polly Timeout policy to move the timeout to per retry instead of total, but the 100 second timeout keeps firing.

I have read about 5 StackOverflow questions that all say to wrap the policies, and I even found the demo on the Polly wiki that say to call `AddPolicyHandler` twice.  That did not work either.  I am sure I have some very basic wrong.  Please explain to me the error of my ways.

I am using .net core 5 preview 7 and current Polly nuget packages.

#### Typed HttpClient registration

```
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<APIWrappers.SendGridClientEmail, APIWrappers.SendGridClientEmail>((c) =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3a/");
})
    .AddPolicyHandler((services, req) => TransientLogAndRetry<APIWrappers.SendGridClientEmail>(services, req)
    .WrapAsync(Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(10)));
```

#### The Policy definition

```
public IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> TransientLogAndRetry<T>(IServiceProvider services, object req)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {typeof(T).Name} - Time: {DateTime.Now}");
    return HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError().
        OrResult((rsp) => rsp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests).
        Or<Polly.Timeout.TimeoutRejectedException>().
        WaitAndRetryAsync(5, GetRetryTime,
#pragma warning disable CS1998
            async (ex, ts, rc, ctx) =>
            {
                ((STS.Diagnostics.LoggerFactory)services.GetService<ILoggerFactory>())?.CreateLogger<T>().
                    Warn(this, "HTTP request above will retry in {0}", ts);
            }
#pragma warning restore CS1998
        );
}
```

#### The delay / penalty calculation

```
private TimeSpan GetRetryTime(int retryCount, DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage> response, Context context)
{
    TimeSpan result;
    long unix;

    Console.WriteLine($"Count: {retryCount} - Time: {DateTime.Now}");
    if (response.Result is null || response.Result.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
        result = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Min(Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(retryCount * 2), 5), 60 * 60));
    else
    {
        unix = response.Result.Headers.GetValues("X-RateLimit-Reset").Select((v) => long.Parse(v)).First();
        result = DateTime.UtcNow - DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(unix);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the provided code I can see the following resilient strategy:

> 100 seconds global timeout
>
> > 5 retries (= 5+1 attempts)
> >
> > Exponential back-off logic
> >
> > > 10 seconds local timeout

---

If I understand your problem correctly then you are looking for a solution to increase the global timeout.

The simplest solution ([1](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#use-case-applying-timeouts)) is to increase the `HttpClient` instance's `Timeout` property from the default 100 to the desired value. If this timeout is exceeded then the instance will throw an `OperationCanceledException` and no further retry attempt can be established.

If the `HttpClient` instance is shared / reused amongst different components then you might need to change the global timeout per usage. You can overcome on this by introducing a new Timeout policy between the HttpClient's global Timeout and your Retry policy.

So, you could end up with the following setup:

> 200 seconds global timeout (by HttpClient
>
> > 150 seconds overall / overarching timeout (by outer timeout policy)
> >
> > > 5 retries (= 5+1 attempts)
> > >
> > > Exponential back-off logic
> > >
> > > > 10 seconds local timeout

In this particular case I would recommend to use `Policy.WrapAsync` ([1](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap)) just like this:

```cs
Policy.WrapAsync(OverallTimeoutPolicy(), RetryPolicy(), LocalTimeoutPolicy());
```

Comment: No, I do not want to increase the global timeout, I want the timeout to be by retry.  If one sets the global time out to 300 seconds (to cover the retries), the first attempt will not timeout for 5 minutes.

Comment: @SOHODeveloper Do I understand correctly that your 10 seconds local timeout has no effect?

Comment: It may have effect.  I have not hit it.  The problem is that the 100 hits during the 3 retry and I never get to the rest of the retries.  I have tested this by forcing what looks like a transient error.  My understanding of the code and comments that I read is that the retry code should 'reset' the global timeout in some way.

Comment: @SOHODeveloper No that's not true. Retry resets only the local timeout (per attempt). From the HttpClient perspective it looks like a single request (all attempts together). It might worth to introduce a **Circuit Breaker** to avoid over-flooding the downstream system. It could open after three successive failed attempts.

Comment: So I should set my global timeout to large number to cover all my retries in wall clock time including the wait time between retries.  You suggested another policy wrap above.  I have not seen a usage like that in the examples or documentation.  Do I need it?  If so please add some explanation for me and future people on why it too is needed.

Comment: @SOHODeveloper Please check Reisenberger's (architect of Polly project) answer of [this issue](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/512). He is a more authentic source than me :D

Comment: @SOHODeveloper Is it sufficient information or should I elaborate?

Comment: Thank you for all your discussion.  I had already read the information in the issue you referenced.  On about the 3 or 4 reading I picked up a word or two that I had missed before and our discussion had me thinking in a different direction, so I interpreted a couple of things differently and I believe I know how to progress.  I am currently not working on this issue, so it will be awhile before I know for sure.  I am marking answered because you stuck with me.  Thanks.

Comment: I am wondering when the `200` seconds timeout of the `HttpClient` would reach in this setup because it seems the `150` sec timeout would trigger earlier.

Comment: @Dr.Strangelove No, that timeout won't be triggered since the global timeout policy fires and then throws a TimeoutRejectedException.